# How to install custom Python package (boto) on Heroku server

Tags: django, python-2.7, heroku, boto

I'm currently using Heroku to host my Python/Django server, and an Amazon S3 to handle my resources.
I have upgraded my Python version from 2.7.6 to 2.7.9, and am now confronted to a new problem: my S3 bucket name contains "." (dots), which causes troubles with boto (I did not have this problem with my previous python version).
I've found on the web how to fix this problem: modify one of the files in boto. I've done that, and it works fine on my local.
(link to that solution: https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2836)

Now, I need to install that new custom version of boto onto my Heroku server. I've thus created a folder to host my custom boto (with setup.py) in my app, and everything works fine when I use `pip install -r requirements.txt` for my virtual environment (requirements.txt contains all the dependencies I need for my app to run). In requirements.txt, I'm now using `-e ./customPythonPackages/boto` instead of simply `boto`.

However, when I try to push on Heroku with the exact same requirements.txt, I get the following error:

`error: package directory 'boto/sdb' does not exist`

I really don't know what's going wrong at that point. I've triple checked the syntax for my requirements.txt file, according to both pip and Heroku (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip).

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

P.S.: I'd like not to change my S3...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to install your custom boto on Heroku, just place your custom boto folder in your project's directory (at the same level as your project's apps).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That's a good solution to my problem, but I think I actually don't do the right thing, in creating my own package. I've found there (http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/boto_config_tut.html) what I think is the correct approach, using a config file.
I don't know for sure where to put my config file to make good use of it... For instance if my app is called "my_app", where should I put the config file?
Lastly, I can't up-vote your answer since I'm a newbie here... :)

Comment: Instead of upvoting, you should be able to 'accept' the answer by clicking the check mark just above the up arrow. As far as the config file, per the docs, it seems like you can create a .boto folder and place the config file there. This may be better as a separate question though. And if you're customizing the boto app, I'd just use the solution as mentioned in the answer.